# Days kept after opening mentioned in packages and how valid are they?

Tags: storage-lifetime, refrigerator, storage, packaging, pita

I bought a pita bread package, that I saw it writes: after opening keep in an airtight container and consume within 2 days.
The thing is that I am keeping it in the refrigerator and it is been more than 2 days and it looks fine.
I don't understand why they mention that taking into account that the package is quite big to be consumed within 2 days anyway (too many pita breads).
Is there something I should be cautious of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a "best before date," which means the pita bread will lose quality after that date.

Pita bread tends to dry out and get stale quickly.

Comment: Agreed on it being the 'best before' date, but there are two styles of pita -- pocket vs. non-pocket.  The pocket stuff dries out quickly, but the non-pocket ones can have mor moisture and you may want to check them for any discoloration or other signs of mold if you're storing them long term

Comment: @Joe: discoloration? How noticeable is that? In case there is something strange and I think it is ok.

Comment: @Joe: You made me now be super suspicious. E.g. I see a small white circle in the size of a needle head in a corner. Is that concerning? I don't remember if it was exactly like that when I bought them

Comment: @Joe: What is a non-pocket pita?

Comment: @Jim : it's flatbread used as a wrap rather than as a pocket to be filled.  https://www.kontos.com/product/pocket-less-pita-white-3/ .  As for the strange discolorations ... they start small and grow, but yeah, they're usually round.  And they're really difficult to distinguish sometimes between leftover flour and patches of white mold.  (green, red, or purple are obvious, though).  When in doubt, cut it out (removing a bit of a margin, as mold sends out tendril-like structures)

Comment: @Joe: I see some of these have a bit larger white circled spots so thanks a lot for the info! I threw away the package earlier when I started having doubts after your comment. Question: Would cutting out only the parts with the spots make it safe to eat?

Comment: @Jim : It's "safer", but maybe not "safe" for everyone.  If you're immune compromised, it's best not to risk it.  If it's just for yourself, it's a personal decision.  I've been known to do it occasionally depending on the situation (most often on refrigerated corn tortillas ... I just don't seem to eat them fast enough).  But like I said, you want to cut wider than the mold is -- probably at least 1/4" / 7mm or so.  You can also toast it to help kill anything that might be left, but even if you kill the mold, that doesn't necessarily break down the toxins that they produced.